# How to update front end Craft new row - stuck on JavaScript

Tags: ajax, javascript, entry-form

I'm building out a front end entry form with a Natrix and everything is coming along fine. However when users create a new row each new row needs to be unique in order to be saved. This is where I'm stuck.

**Simplified HTML:**

```
<div class="matrixblock">
    <p>
    block id: new_0
</p>

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="text" name="fields[staffProfiles][new_0][fields][employeeName]" value="" placeholder="Full Name">
</div><!-- /.col-sm-6 -->
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="text" name="fields[staffProfiles][new_0][fields][jobTitle]" value=""  placeholder="Job Title">
</div><!-- /.col-sm-6 -->


<a href="" class="remove-row"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>


</div><!-- /.matrixblock -->
```

**JS:**

```
var blocknum = 0;

// add a new person
$('#addPerson').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('clicked addPerson');

    //iterate blocknumber
    blocknum = blocknum+= 1;
    console.log('blocknum is ' + blocknum);

    var newPerson = "<div class='newperson'></div>";
    $('.newBlock').append(newPerson);
    $('.newBlock .newperson:last-child').load('/store/newperson');

    // replace all instances of new_0 with new1, new2 etc.. as rows added
    // this line doesn't do anything, why?
    $('.newBlock .newperson:last-child').replace('new_0','new' + blocknum);

})
```

`console.log('blocknum is ' + blocknum);` is showing that the blocknum is increasing with each row. the **Replace** in the last line of javascript is just not doing anything.

The new person row gets added via ajax correctly but each time it's added [new_0] needs to be unique, but nothing I'm trying is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I didn't get this working with replacing the new_0 in the fields array of the ajax content.

I opted instead to limit adding new people to one at a time by having the new person button fade out when clicked and a message appearing stating:

> **You must save your entry to add more staff**

In the end this forces the store manager to save their work more often, which is always a good thing, and keeps the javascript simpler. Functionality that is required is working. Would be nice to add multiple people at a time, but for now a solution that everyone is happy with.

new javascript code is below. the .addMorePeople fadein contains the message about saving the entry.

```
// add a new person
$('#addPerson').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('clicked addPerson');

    var newPerson = "<div class='newperson'></div>";
    $('.newBlock').append(newPerson);
    $('.newBlock .newperson:last-child').load('/store/newperson');

    // hide add button so that they must save to add more
    $(this).fadeOut("slow", function(){
        $this.remove();
    });
    $('.addMorePeople').fadeIn('slow');

    {# load redactor on the new row #}
    {% includeJs "$('.newperson:last-child .employeeBio').redactor();" %}

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of rows you already have from the DOM, then use that to determine how many you'll have after you add a new one.

```
$('#addPerson').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('clicked addPerson');

  var newPerson = "<div class='newperson'></div>";
  $('.newBlock').append(newPerson);
  $('.newBlock .newperson:last-child').load('/store/newperson');

  var blocknum = $('.newBlock .newperson').length;
  $('.newBlock .newperson:last-child').replace('new_0','new' + blocknum);
});
```

<del>Also note that in your example you were replacing using `$blocknum`, but you had defined it to be `blocknum` without the `$`.</del> You've already fixed this :)

Hope this works out!

Comment: doing this I get an Uncaught TypeError: $(..).replace is not a function --- actually with my original code I get that too.. just checked.

Comment: Ah I see; if you're trying to update the `name` attribute, you'd want to define it as a separate variable. It'll be a string, and you can use the string's `replace()` method. Then, set the `name` attribute to be the new one you just made (using `replace`).